# Passing values to MySQL IN operation in PDO prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form field that is returning a comma-delimited string that I want to pass in to a PHP PDO MySQL query IN operation, but the IN operation requires that the values be comma-delimited (as opposed to my ***string*** of delimited values).

How do I do this?

```
$values = $_POST['values']; # '10,5,4,3' (string)
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (:values)";
$data = array( ':values' => $values );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't pass in multiple values in a single placeholder. You will have to enter a different placeholder for each value to be passed into `IN ()`. Since you don't know how many there will be, use `?` instead of named parameters.

```
$values = explode(',', $values) ;

$placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($values)), ', ') ;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($placeholders)";

$stm = $db->prepare($query) ;
$stm->execute($values) ;
```

Comment: +1 Nice, I would however, do the following: `$values = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $values)), 'is_numeric');`, you never know what comes from the user input...

Comment: Your syntax is reversed for `rtrim`: should be `rtrim(str_repeat('? ,', count($values)), ', ');`. But otherwise this is the solution I went with. Thanks!

Comment: @neezer ack, cheers. Silly php with its inconsistent parameter ordering :)

Comment: @Alix ofcourse, sanitation should be applied to all user input.. maybe a bit wider than this question's scope imo, but always good advice.

Comment: Sidenote, look at @mfonda's comment to his own answer for a slightly more elegant way of making up `$placeholders` as such: `$str = str_repeat('?,', $count - 1) . '?';` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729679/passing-values-to-mysql-in-operation-in-pdo-prepared-statement/4729898#4729898

Answer (score 1):

PDO alone cannot bind arrays to a `:parameter`. You need a helper function for that.

Also in your example, the literal string `'10,5,4,3'` would be received as one value. Parameter binding will turn it into `.. id IN ('10,5,4,3')` and not into a list comparison.

The workaround in your case would be to fall back on using dynamic SQL and escaping.

```
$values = preg_replace('/[^\d,]/', "", $_POST['values']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($values)";
```

I'm personally using a wrapper/helper [function](http://sourceforge.net/p/php7framework/svn/30/tree/trunk/php7/db.php?format=raw) which has a special syntax for arrays (but you don't actually have one to begin with, so it would be a double workaround):

```
db("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (??)", explode(",",$values));
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to recognize that `$values` is a bunch of individual values, and set up your query with this in mind. This is easier to do if you use `?` placeholders instead of named placeholders. For example, you could do something like the following:

```
$values = explode(',', $_POST['values']); //array(10,5,4,3)
$placeholder_string = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?')); // string '?,?,?,?'
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($placeholder_string)";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($values);
```

Comment: I see your `array_fill` and I raise you a `str_repeat` :)

Comment: To be completely honest I've found myself doing this on occasion. It may be creating an array for no reason but it's just more elegant than creating a string and then having to cut off the excess characters :)

Comment: @Fanis I think it makes more sense semantically--you're building the correct string in the first place. But something like `$str = str_repeat('?,', $count - 1) . '?';` is probably the most ideal way, now that I think about it.

Comment: that is indeed more efficient and more elegant. I will be using this, thanks. Just need to make sure to add a nice descriptive comment nearby :)