# Creating an SQL query with MySQL PDO with enabled/disabled filter variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, combinations

This might be somewhat of an odd question, but I'm trying to create a filter for results, but the means of creating a query seems kind of odd to me.

Say I have 5 types of animals, by default it searches all types of animals, however then you can filter them.

So say we have Cats, Dogs, Reptiles, Birds, Fish. I want to filter out the fish and birds, how would I build a query to notice this? Do I really have to build a query for every single possible combination? That seems a little absurd.

example query for all:

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE type = "dogs" OR type = "cats" OR type = "reptiles" OR type = "fish" OR type = "birds"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`NOT IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in) operator.  For example, to filter out `fish` and `birds`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE type NOT IN ('fish', 'birds')
```

Comment: Fantastic, I still need to figure out how to properly do that with PDO but this is certainly a better solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Ian:  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729679/passing-values-to-mysql-in-operation-in-pdo-prepared-statement) for ideas on how to pass such a list into a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('fish', 'birds');
$filter = implode(",", $array);

"SELECT * FROM animals WHERE type NOT IN ($filter)"
```

This way you can dynamically fill your array and pass it to sql query.

Comment: Better to pass the array in as parameters to a prepared statement in order to ensure that its elements don't get evaluated for SQL.

Comment: Yeah, still can't get that working properly. I set it up so it properly creates the string as $limit = "'fish', 'birds'" but when I try to use bindParam it fails. Works fine if I just plug it in as $limit though.